# Prevent opening the image in browser when drop image file in Vue

Tags: vue.js

When I drag the image above `label` and realize the left button of my mouse, files opens in my browser. So, `prevent` modified in not enough to avoid this default behavior. What else I need to do?

Note: below layout already uses for handing the click event.

```html
<div class="ImagesUploader"></div>
  <label 
    class="ImagesUploader-ClickableDragAndDropArea"
    role="button"
    @dragover.prevent="onDragOperationStarted"
    @dragleave.prevent="onDragOperationTerminated"
    @drop.prevent="onDrop"
  >
    <input 
      type="file" 
      class="ImagesUploader-HiddenOriginalInput"
      @change="onSelectNewImages"
      accept="image/*,image/jpeg"
    />      
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56167681/drag-and-drop-in-vue-js-without-component

Comment: @Shoejep, Yes, the second answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [drag and drop in vue js without component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56167681/drag-and-drop-in-vue-js-without-component)

Comment: @Shoejep Uncleanly, but answers. The "Prevent opening the image in browser when drop image file in Vue" and "Drag and drop in vue js without component" are different search requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `@drop.stop.prevent` required.
The handling will be like:

```
onDrop(event) {
  const file = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
  // ...
}
``
```